# Bug identification - Beetle, grasshopper, moth-like and it also flies

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image] Could anyone please help me identify this creature? It can fly and seems to like crawling as well. It has mandibles that are beetle-like.  Approximately 3cm/2inch. Location: KwaZulu Natal, South Africa

Comment: Hi Ari13, and welcome to Bio.SE! Please update your question with the approximate size of your specimen, and please provide any additional information or pictures that are possible. **See [tag:species-identification] tag question guidelines [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info).** Doing so will increase the positive voting response your question receives as well as increase the odds of receiving a good/accurate answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Updated with approximate size and location. 

Answer (score 1):

That is a mole cricket, Order Orthoptera, family Gryllotalpidae
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_cricket

Comment: Thank you! Odd that I would've found it down here though? Don't you think?

Comment: You mean in South Africa? No, they are cosmopolitan. Cool bugs!